# cannot perform sql injection on a unsecure form

Tags: php, mysql, security, sql-injection

Trying to perform an sql injection on my database.

I haven't escaped the string I'm inserting into the query so I don't understand what is preventing me from getting all user ids when inserting: username or 1=1 into the username input box. Works like a charm when I hardcode 1=1 into the raw query.

I haven't got anything else on the server that would be causing this, all I have is an index.php with the below code.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = 'SELECT ID FROM users WHERE username = "'.$_POST["username"].'"';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
print_r($result);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "id: " . $row["ID"];
        print_r($row);
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

?>
<form method='POST' action='#'>
        username <input type'text' name='username'></input>
        <br>
        password <input type'text' name='password'></input>
        <input type='submit'>
    </form>
    <?php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to end the quote of the SQL in the posted username. And finish the final quote so its not a syntax error. Easy way is to make it into the 1=1 version in strings. `""=""`.

So:

```
" or ""="
```

Comment: why didn't you suggest him to use `prepare()` and `bind_param()` method as he is using `mysqli`?

Comment: it seemed to be more a question of how SQL injection works rather than how to perform secure programming. But if that wasn't the case, use prepared statements and param functions like above.

Comment: Well, to be honest, you could/should ask him to use those methods instead of what he's doing. Thus he and other users who will see this answer will use them and will never come back with old vulnerable sql query. However you could add this at the bottom of you answer.

Comment: I know how to protect against this. Just wanted to test it out on an unsecured query, to see it in action. Thanks again for all your help guys.